# java nashorn, how to add code to a constructor

Tags: java, nashorn

How can i add code to a construtor of a javascript class.
The code in Java is very simple:

```
public class MyObject extends SomeAbstractObject {
  public MyObject() {
     super();
     System.out.println("hello");
  }
}
```

I know that its possible to extend java class like this (let's assume i did some bindings):

```
var myJSClass= Java.extend(SomeAbstractObject.static 
     {methods i want to override}
})
```

But how can i replicate my java example in javascript and nashorn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Nashorn generates constructors for the subclass - these can not be "customized". While you can override non-final methods by script functions, you can't "extend" constructors.

Comment: If you want to have additional state and initialize for subclass, you can use additional properties in the object literal